# Angular: How To Assign Index Value From Dropdown For LocalValue After Button Click

Tags: angular, typescript

Just Want To Know How To Assign *Index*(let i = index" **[value]="i"**) Value To    ***EmployeeIndex : any;*** after button click

I look forward to any of your suggestions

There Is My Code::

**HTML**

```
             <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="EmployeeName">
                <option *ngFor="let employeeItem of getEmployeeeList(); let i = index" [value]="i">
                       {{employeeItem.EmployeeName}}
                </option>
            </select>

    <button (click)="updateBook()" *ngIf="dep.No!=0" class="btn btn-primary">
    Update
</button>
```

**TS**

```
 EmployeeIndex : any;

 updateBook()
  {
    this.EmployeeId = this.employeeFiltered[this.EmployeeIndex].EmployeeId;
    
    var val = {
      No:this.No,
      EmployerName:this.EmployerName,
      EmployeeName:this.EmployeeName,
      Project:this.Project,
      Date:this.Date,
      Spent:this.Spent,
      VAT:this.VAT,
      Total:this.Total,
      Comment:this.Comment};

      this.service.updateBook(val).subscribe(res=>{
        alert(res.toString());
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This One working, using (change) event , but I really need something like (click) assign event..

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="EmployeeName" (change)="onChangeEmployee($event)">
                <option *ngFor="let employeeItem of getEmployeeeList(); let i = index" [value]="i">
                       {{employeeItem.EmployeeName}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

**TS**

```
onChangeEmployee(event: any)
{
  console.log("EmployeeIndex " + this.employeeFiltered[event.target.value].EmployeeId); // 0
}
```